# How to request a user to give me access token for a particular app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

User is already authorised to use my Facebook app. The app provides a form where user needs to enter his app ID. There is also a form input that requests to enter the access token for that particular app. The problem is that giving user instructions:

> Please provide access token for your app. This information can be
>   retrieved by going to
>   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[your
>   app ID]&client_secret=[your app secret].

It's not user-friendly. Is there any alternative? Such as.. a popup with a callback?

Comment: Why would users want to give you access tokens to other applications they are using? Why would you want to ask for such a thing?

Comment: @NitzanTomer, sign NDA and I will gladly disclose such information.

Comment: Sign? It's you who are asking for help. in any case, this question is not for SO, it's not a programming question. There's no "right way" of doing what you want, facebook hasn't introduced such functionality in their api.

Comment: @NitzanTomer SO is a place to ask questions to `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`. At which sentence my question goes out of the scope with the definition.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use an app access token, I'm not sure if that's possible.

You could call `/me/accounts` with `manage_pages` permissions to get *user* access tokens.